# On touch devices: Apply a background color change when user touches heading

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I have a website and I want (only on touch devices, such as an iPhone) the `<h2>` to have a different background colour when a user touches the heading.

[image]

Is this possible with pure HTML5 / CSS3? Assume users are using the latest browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `:active` pseudo class in order to achieve this.

```
h2:active { 
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

You can use MQ for limiting the applying of this pseudo class only under the desired resolution, where the mouse click event is unavaliable. For example:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) { 
  h2:active { 
   background-color: yellow;
  }
}
```

Comment: That will apply the style when the `h2` element is clicked with a mouse too.

Comment: You should include that in your answer, so.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, I think you need to use JS for this.

Neither CSS nor HTML have any way to express the changes you wish to apply when touching the header (or any other element for that matter).

Comment: And what JavaScript should they use? If you're just saying that they should use JS then thi should be posted as a comment, not an answer.